# Recursive function not working as expected when mapping through nested elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to recursively map through an array of objects, which could have the same type of objects nested in themselves.

i.e.,

```
type TOption = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  options?: TOption;
}
const options = [
  { id: "1", name: "Option 1" },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Option 2",
    options: [
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Option 3",
        options: [
          {
            id: "4",
            name: "Option 4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { id: "5", name: "Option 5" }
] as TOption[];
```

A bit of a premise, I am trying to build a navbar menu, where each element of type `TOption` can have a submenu of `options` field of type `TOption` as well. Based on the `level`, I will be offsetting that nested menu off-div / off-screen.

Anyway, I'm running into a bit of trouble when I traverse through the array. Here is my JS-ified `recurse` method (the actual `React.useCallback` function can be seen in the Sandbox below),

```
  const recurse = React.useCallback(
    ({ options, level }) =>
      options.map(({ id, name, options: subOptions = [] }) =>
        subOptions.length ? (
          recurse({ options: subOptions, level: level + 1 })
        ) : (
          console.log(`My id is {id} and I'm at level {level}`)
        )
      ),
    []
  );
```

The above outputs,

```
My id is 1 and I'm at level 1 
My id is 4 and I'm at level 3 
My id is 5 and I'm at level 1
```

It's clearly only going into the elements that have a submenu, and the recursion ends with a menu that does not have a submenu.

How can I change this up, so that the output becomes,

```
My id is 1 and I'm at level 1
My id is 2 and I'm at level 1
My id is 3 and I'm at level 2
My id is 4 and I'm at level 3
My id is 5 and I'm at level 1
// Where those at level 1 would be displayed in the "parent" menu,
// and those at level 2 would be a secondary submenu of that parent menu,
// and those at level 3 would a submenu of a secondary menu.
```

An example of a menu at level 3 would be `Settings -> Layout -> Theme`, and the structure of that would be,

```
const options = [
  ...restOfOptions
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Settings",         // level 1
    options: [
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Layout",       // level 2
        options: [
          {
            id: "4",
            name: "Theme",    // level 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

The problem here is that if a submenu exists, then the function will return whichever last submenu exists in that tree.

[image: divine-fire-6fq7q]

In the sandbox, the output is,

```
My id is 1 and I'm at level 1
        My id is 4 and I'm at level 3
            My id is 6 and I'm at level 4
My id is 7 and I'm at level 1
```

but I'm looking for,

```
My id is 1 and I'm at level 1
My id is 2 and I'm at level 1
    My id is 3 and I'm at level 2
        My id is 4 and I'm at level 3
        My id is 5 and I'm at level 3
            My id is 6 and I'm at level 4
My id is 7 and I'm at level 7
```

Comment: I suppose none of the answers did help you in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion can be used to unpack your elements at any depth.
This is how you could plug in this recursive solution into your function:

```
function rec(arr) {

  arr.forEach((elem) => {
    if (elem.options === undefined) { // belongs to level 1
        console.log("Element id", elem.id)
    }
    else {
        for (let a in elem.options) {
            console.log("Element id", elem.id)
            return `Element id: ${elem.id} ${rec([elem.options[a]])}`;
        }
    }   
        
  });
}
```

Test:

```
rec(options);

/**
* Element id 1
* Element id 2
* Element id 3
* Element id 4
* Element id 5
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "subOptions.length" control, if there are sub options, you will not write the current data because you use recurse.

In fact, you need to write the current data first and then call it if it has a sub option.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this :

```
       const recurse = React.useCallback(
         ({ options, level }) =>
           options.map(({ id, name, options: subOptions = [] }) =>{
              console.log(level)
    
              let elem=[];
              let smallelem=subOptions.length>0 ? (
               recurse({ options: subOptions, level: level + 1 })
               ):null;
              elem.push(<div key={id} style={{ paddingLeft: level === 1 ? 0 : level * 40 }}>
                   My id is {id} and I'm at level {level}
                </div>)
              elem.push(smallelem)
              return elem;
         }
        ),
      []
      );
```